# Can we rotate Gradient in andengine?

Tags: java, rotation, andengine, gradient

Is there any way to rotate Gradient in andengine? It is from left to right. I want it to be from top to bottom or from bottom to top.
I have used the following code now I want to rotate 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

```
    Gradient g = new Gradient(100, 100, GameActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH/4,GameActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT/4, vbom);
    g.setGradient(Color.GREEN, Color.RED, 1, 0);        
    g.setGradientDitherEnabled(true);
    attachChild(g);
```

Thanks for your replies...

Comment: We can use   g.setRotation(angle);  to rotate the gradient...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
gradientObj.setRotation(angle);
```

to rotate the gradient.